# Angular 11 Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am receiving the following error in my code.

```
TS2739  (TS) Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'WeatherForecast': ID, date, temperatureC, temperatureF, summary
```

I'm not sure why this is happening since my object is holding the variables? My service created from ApiService includes the object WeatherForecast which also does hold the specified variable like so.

```
export class WeatherForecast {
  ID: number
  date: number
  temperatureC: number
  temperatureF: number
  summary: string
}
```

This is the new component file created for editing the weather forecast table.

```
export class EditWeatherForecastComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Edit Data';
  baseUrl: string;
  ID: number;

  forecast: WeatherForecast = {
    ID: 0,
    date: 0,
    temperatureC: 0,
    temperatureF: 0,
    summary: ''
  };

  constructor(private service: ApiService, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public http: HttpClient, private router: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347/WeatherForecast";
  }

  forecasts: any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshWeatherList();
    this.ID = +this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('ID');

    this.forecast = this.service.getWeatherListID(this.ID);  //ERROR HERE
  }

  refreshWeatherList() {
    this.service.getForecast().subscribe(data => {
      this.forecasts = data;
    });
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    let forecasts: WeatherForecast = {
      ID: form.value.id,
      date: form.value.id,
      temperatureC: form.value.id,
      temperatureF: form.value.id,
      summary: form.value.id
    }
    
  }


}
```

This is the service

```
getWeatherListID(ID: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/?ID=' + ID)
  }
```

Comment: Your problem is probably in service.gettWeatherListID()..

Comment: I have added the code for the service.getWeatherListID

Comment: `return this.http.get<WeatherForecast>(this.baseURL + '/?ID=' + ID)` should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your service, the following line returns an Observable, wich is normal.

```
return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/?ID=' + ID)
```

But in your component, your're saying, "Hey, my variable forecast have the following type"

```
WeatherForecast
```

And then, your're saying "Ok, im defining the forecast variable wich is type WeatherForecast with a result that have type Observable". This is not possible.

There are many ways to do it, but you can try it:

```
this.service.getWeatherListID(this.ID).subscribe((response:WeatherForecast) => {
    this.forecast = response;
});
```

Doing it like that: Your script will wait for the http call to be done, and then, assign the response into your forecast variable.

Comment: I don't believe this will work as an Observable doesn't have a `then` method on it.

Comment: Thank you, subscribe is better.

Comment: I believe this solved my issue however my table values still do no appear in my form I created. Could it be an issue with my HTML?

Comment: thanks for posting a clear, working sample with precisely enough info to understand. made my code work :)

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the relevant parts of your question,

`EditWeatherForecastComponent` is defining a property as follows:

```
forecast: WeatherForecast;
```

The definition for WeatherForecast is

```
export class WeatherForecast {
  ID: number
  date: number
  temperatureC: number
  temperatureF: number
  summary: string
}
```

In the service, the relevant function is defined as follows:

```
getWeatherListID(ID: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/?ID=' + ID)
}
```

Angular's `HttpClient` has a few (overloaded) methods, get being one of them. Angular doesn't know what type of object your api is returning. The two relevant to your question though are the following.

[image]

Since `get` can accept a type, but doesn't require one, when one isn't provided, the framework will assume an `Object` is being returned. A JavaScript object though doesn't contain the properties that the `forecast` property in the `EditWeatherForecastComponent` are expecting, namely the ones defined in the `WeatherForecast` class(i.e. ID, date, temperatureC, temperatureF, summary) which is why you are receiving the error. The way to fix it would be to use one of the other function definitions for `get`, specifically the one where you give it type information. That can be done as follows:

```
return this.http.get<WeatherForecast>(this.baseURL + '/?ID=' + ID)
```